# Orchard CMS - Alternate for MediaPickerField in Blog Posts

Tags: themes, orchardcms

I have added a MediaPickerField to my the BlogPost part so that I can display an image as part of every blog post. The problem I am having is that the Media template is setting Layout.Title which is making the image title show up in my tabs instead of my blog post title.

Shape tracer is showing:

- Fields_MediaLibraryPicker

  - Media

I can override Media.cshtml or Media-Image.cshtml in my theme, but I really want to only override for my blogposts. Is there a way to use an alternate to override Media.cshtml (specifically to get rid of Layout.Title = mediaPart.Title) in a way that only shows up in my blog post pages?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Please file a bug.

Comment: I reverted to default theme and problem went away, so I'll need to see if I can identify which scenario in my custom theme is causing the issue to trigger. Thanks for confirming this is not the expected behavior.